# Why does my command stop working when I put it into an alias?

Tags: zsh, alias, zshrc, comm, pacman-package-manager

I am trying to run the following command
`comm -23 <(pacman -Qqe | sort) <(awk '{print $1}' /desktopfs-pkgs.txt | sort)`

I get the following output

```
autoconf
automake
bison
chromium
code
discord
fakeroot
flex
lib32-mesa-vdpau
lib32-vulkan-intel
lib32-vulkan-radeon
m4
make
mesa-vdpau
nerd-fonts-complete
paru
patch
pkgconf
spotify
terminator
vim
vulkan-intel
vulkan-radeon
xf86-video-amdgpu
xf86-video-ati
xf86-video-intel
xf86-video-nouveau
```

My goal is to have it output to me the difference between packages I explicitly installed vs what came with Manjaro.

It correctly gives me the output I want and works fine, but when I put it into an alias within my `zshrc`, it fails.

In my `zshrc` it looks as follows
`alias paccom="comm -23 <(pacman -Qqe | sort) <(awk '{print $1}' /desktopfs-pkgs.txt | sort)"`

After sourcing, the following is outputted.

```
~: paccom                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ✔   
acpi
acpid
adobe-source-han-sans-cn-fonts
adobe-source-han-sans-jp-fonts
adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts
adobe-source-sans-fonts
alsa-firmware
alsa-utils
amd-ucode
android-tools
android-udev
ark
autoconf
automake
avahi
b43-fwcutter
bison
...
```

Basically, it seems like the entirety of `pacman -Qqe`, as if its not actually doing the file comparison correctly.

Any thoughts as to why the behavior changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $1 is substituted by the shell at the time the alias is defined, i.e. awk never sees a `$1`. You can verify this by displaying your alias with

```
alias paccom
```

You would have to escape the in the alias `$` to prevent substitution, or better yet (to save you further headaches) define a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks! I'll go ahead and define a function instead.